# Looking for datastructure that maintains a size & purges older elements in the process

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

**Usecase** maintain a list of the last n visited URLs (where n is a fix number). As new URLs are added to the list, older urls are removed automatically (in order to keep it at n elements)

**Requirement** The data structure needs to be sorted by time (should be no problem if it accepts a Comparator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java there are several implementation of [Queue](http://localhost/api/java6/java/util/Queue.html). It should be trivial to inherit or warp an existing implementation and implement the add() method like this:

```
boolean add(E e) {
  if(q.size()==MAX_SIZE) {
    remove();
  }
  q.add(e)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need a circular buffer.

Just keep an array b[] of size N and index k, that points to the oldest URL. Every time you need to add new URL, assign it to b[k] and increment k, wrapping it if needed: k = (k + 1) % N.

All your URLs will be naturally sorted, the oldest is at k, the second oldest at k+1, and so on, the newest is at k-1. (The sequence wraps at the end of the array).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [circular buffer](http://cs.fit.edu/~mmahoney/cis5100/examples/ch23/fig23_13_14/CircularBuffer.java) of size `n`

Answer (score 0):

Override `TreeSet` and create a `Proxy` for `URL` that also stores the time visited.
Then either create a `Comparator` or implement `Comparable` and override `equals` and `hashCode`.

For overriding `TreeSet` [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929682/datastructure-with-fixed-size-and-unique-elements) could help you.

You need to override the `add` method. Since you probably don't need `addAll`, you could throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

After that you should be fine, you even could do stuff like revisited URLs are stored with each visiting time (that means different ProxyURLs that point to same URL) *or* just one entry per URL. It depends on how you define the `equals` (and corresponding the `hashCode`, respectively the `compare`)
method.

**Watch out**: `TreeSet` uses the `compare` method for equality check and **not** the equals method.