# Datastructure with fixed size and unique elements

Tags: java, data-structures, set

I'm searching for a datastructure that fits my needs:

- Contained elements must be unique.
- Fixed size, i. e. add should return `false` (or throw  anexception), if size is exceeded.

Additional:

- Keep stored elements in order.

First thing that came to my mind was `Set`. Overriding the `add` method of `TreeSet` for instance. Or using decorator pattern.

Are there any other suited classes to reduce the coding and logic effort on my side?

Comment: Just a note: it appears you're not looking for a datastructure, but just for a class with suitable behavior. Inventing optimal datastructures is a "bit" more involved---and rewarding.

Comment: Where is the difference here? I don't quite get you. A possibility would also be to use a PQ relying on a Heap backed by an fixed-size array. So I would say, the question is about datastructures. One could even consider the time complexity of the operations I want to use. And yes, inventing and even recombining datastructures is not trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

extend `TreeSet` override `add()`, `addAll()` method to look for `size()` and number of element being added, also consider synchronization to be strict about multiple threads

Comment: This seems like the best idea and requires just a few extra lines in the extended class.

Answer (score 0):

There also an alternative way, you can use normal hashset or set and while write method to check for size, if the size exceeds boolean will return true else it will return `false`, and can do the needful when required.

```
public void isSetFull() {
    // n is the max size you want for set
    if (set.size() >= n) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```